# Some tips to improve a bash script for count fastq files

Tags: bash, shell, fastq

Hi guys I got this bash one line that i wish to make a script

```
for i in 'ls *.fastq.gz'; do echo $(zcat ${i} | wc -l)/4|bc; done
```

I would like to make it as a script to read from a data dir and print out the result with the name of the file.

I tried to put the dir in front of the 'data/*.fastq.gz' but got am error No such dir exist...

I would like some like this:

```
name1.fastq.gz 1898516
name2.fastq.gz 2467421
namen.fastq.gz 1234532
```

I am not experienced in bash.

Could you guys give a help?
 Thanks

Comment: Could you please post sample input of how files are and sample of expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: BTW [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is really useful for debugging shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to escape to `bc` for integer math (divide by 4), or to use 'ls' to enumerate the files. The original version will do with minor changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="${1-.}"

for i in "$dir"/*.fastq.gz; do
  lines=$(zcat "${i}" | wc -l)
  printf '%s %d\n' "$i" "$((lines/4))"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the dir as an argument, but default to the current dir if it's not set.

```
dir="${1-.}"
```

Then put it in the glob: `"$dir"/*.fastq.gz`

As well:

- [Quote variables](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) and [command expansions](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046).
- [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- Don't trust `echo` with arbitrary data (filenames). [Use `printf` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117037).
- Use an end-of-options flag `--` when giving filenames to commands.
- I prefer to not have any inline command expansions, but that's just personal preference

Putting it together:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="${1-.}"

for file in "$dir"/*.fastq.gz; do
    printf '%s ' "$file"
    lines="$(zcat -- "$file" | wc -l)"
    bc <<< "$lines/4"  # Using a here-string (Bash feature)
done
```

Comment: Any good reason to prefer `bc` over bash arithmetic like `$((stuff/4))`? Why use `printf` instead of just `echo -n "$file "`?

Comment: @Harald `bc` can output floats; Bash can't. Regarding `echo` vs `printf`, check out [the link I mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117037).